# How do I combine two tables that have only a few similar columns?

Tags: sql

I'm attempting to combine two tables, both of which aren't related in any way except for a few columns (ID, Created Date, Country, etc.). In essence, I simply want to append one table to another. However, I would like to combine the columns that are similar and add on the columns that are not similar. I've attempted a Union, but my tables don't have the same number of columns. Currently, I'm working with this:

```
SELECT * FROM `leads`, `opportunity`
where `leads`.`Id` = `opportunity`.`Id`
```

which doesn't really work when I want to use this new query as a subquery elsewhere. Additionally, the fields in each table can change at any time, so I’m never sure which columns are matching or non-matching. I simply want to append the rows from one table onto the other while automatically combining columns with identical names. I feel like I'm missing something obvious...

*NOTE: I am doing this within DOMO, so I have a few more limitations than I normally would.*

Comment: Is what you are looking for a "JOIN"? Find any decent SQL tutorial, and it will be one of the first 3 lessons. (What you've written there is actually how joins were written in pre-historic versions of SQL, about 30 years ago.) If that's not what you mean, then please click [edit] to include some sample input and what you want the output to be.

Comment: Are the id of leads and id of opportunity same?

Comment: [Full Join](https://www.dofactory.com/sql/full-outer-join)

Comment: If you use ```UNION``` then just fill the non-matching columns with ```NULL```

Comment: @IMSoP I attempted to use a JOIN but there are a very large amount of columns, and I don’t know how many or which ones to JOIN ON

Comment: @alexherm there are legitimately like 50 columns that are non-matching, and I’m not sure which ones they are. I just want it to append the rows from one table to the other, while matching up similar columns that have identical names. Do I have to specify each column like in a JOIN, or can I automate it?

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use joins

```
SELECT * FROM `leads` JOIN `opportunity`
on  `leads`.`Id` = `opportunity`.`Id`
```

and to get only selected columns

```
SELECT leads.column_name, opportunity.column_name FROM `leads` JOIN `opportunity`
on  `leads`.`Id` = `opportunity`.`Id`
```

Comment: I tried this, but there are other columns that also match between tables. I can't simply match them all to each other, because I don't know how many or which columns match.

Comment: What columns are you trying to get? If you issue is the same column names then you can use aliases
SELECT * FROM `leads as t1` JOIN `opportunity as t2`
on  `t1`.`Id` = `t2`.`Id`

Comment: I'm trying to get all of the columns from both tables, but I don't know how many columns match between tables

Comment: match them on the condition that is required